# Make portable Mysql and NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite

I'm needing to make a stand-alone application with NodeJS for Windows, Mac, and Linux

My first option for the database was SQLite but it's very small for my big data

My reason for using MySQL is that support many data and it's quickly

But the big problem is installing MySQL that it's hard to install it with end-user

And the important note is I packaging the NodeJS project and convert to exe file

Also, I use mosquito broker in this project and still no problem in the run this application.

Can I use MySQL like SQLite (stand-alone)?

Thanks

Comment: Read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) and read there "SQLite supports databases up to 140 terabytes in size", so .... Why do you make the statement "SQLite but it's very small for my big data" ?

Comment: @Luuk Yes, you right but how much performance of SQLite than MySQL?
example for 1000 records,SQLite speed is equal to MySQL?

Comment: 1000 records is not "big data", you can even do that in Excel with comparable speed to MySQL or SQLite

Comment: [release notes 3.33.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_33_0.html) "Increase the maximum size of database files to 281 TB."   I hope no one ever says "SQLite but it's very small for my big data"   

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad if you think Sqlite is weak

Because it's the best choice for your needing

It's simple, high performance, stand-alone and many features

My suggestion is using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decide to use the same Sqlite because :

"SQLite supports databases up to 140 terabytes in size"

Also, I assign database file for each device and I think that is the best solution without Mysql database

Comment: Although I don't know what you're storing, there's a fairly high chance that "_I assign database file for each device_" is not the best solution. If the data stored _about_ each  device is of the same type, it is _usually_ better to have one table with a `DeviceName` field or similar than separate tables called `Device1`, `Device2`, ... etc. You're not going to "break" SQLite by having one long table.